# how to copy last row to another excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel document which gets data from Google Finance in one sheet. What I want is to copy the last row in this first sheet to another sheet in the same Workbook.

This is the code I am using

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

ws1.Range("A1:E100").ClearContents
'CS = "URL;https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=NIFTY&i=900&p=3d&f=o,h,l,c"

CS2 = ws2.Range("A3").Value
CS1 = CS2 & "&i=900&p=3d&f=o,h,l,c"
CS = "URL;https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=" & CS1

ws1.Select

With ws1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=CS, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

    .Name = "getprices?q=NIFTY&i=900&p=3d&f=o,h,l,c_12"
    .FieldNames = True
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Rows("1:7").Select
Range("A7").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:A").Select

Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True

Selection.ColumnWidth = 10.86
Range("F7").Select
End Sub
```

Please help me to copy and paste to another sheet, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code in your function to **copy** the whole **last row** and **paste** it in **another sheet**.

In my code I assumed your data where in column A so I copied the last row where column **A** is not empty.

If you want to change it, change the value of **1** in `(ws1.Rows.Count, 1)` with the number of the column where your data are located (for example `(ws1.Rows.Count, 4)` if your data are in column **D** since it's the 4th column).

```
'Variable for the destination
Dim destinationRow As Integer

'Row in the second sheet where it will be paste
destinationRow = 5

'Copy th last row in your first sheet
ws1.Rows(ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1).EntireRow.Copy

'Paste it in the second sheet
ws2.Rows(destinationRow).PasteSpecial
```

---

### What you need to change

Change the value of **5** in `destinationRow = 5` to the destination row (the row in the second sheet where it will be paste).

For example
`destinationRow = 7` To paste it at the 7th row in the second sheet or `destinationRow = 6` to paste it the the 6th row in the second sheet.

Comment: hi, the last row is blank !

Comment: Actually when the data gets filled, the last row is blank! I want the second row from the last